# form:error tag exists in jsp file but disappear in the page source code

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm using spring mvc 2.5.6, bootstrap3.3.2, the jsp file is:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="springForm" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <%--<link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">--%>

    <title>Device check</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/bootstrap/css/device.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        .error {
            color: #ee0d25;
        }
    </style>

</head>
    <body>

            <form class="form-device" method="POST" command="queryForm">
                <h2 class="form-device-heading">Please fill the form</h2>

                <label for="deviceId" class="sr-only">deviceId</label>
                <input type="text" name="deviceId" id="deviceId" class="form-control" placeholder="deviceId">
                <td><form:errors path="deviceId" cssClass="error" /></td>

                <label for="startTime" class="sr-only">startTime</label>
                <input type="text" name="startTime" id="startTime" class="form-control" placeholder="startTime">
                <td><form:errors path="startTime" cssClass="error" /></td>


                <label for="endTime" class="sr-only">endTime</label>
                <input type="text" name="endTime" id="endTime" class="form-control" placeholder="endTime">
                <td><form:errors path="endTime" cssClass="error" /></td>


                <label for="environment" class="sr-only">environmnet</label>
                <input type="text" name="environment" id="environment" class="form-control"
                       placeholder="daily or online">
                <td><form:errors path="environment" cssClass="error" /></td>

                <div class="checkbox">
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

four input box here and validate them with spring's validator. but when I visit localhost:8080/form.htm, the source code of web page looks like:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Device check</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="/wsf-ops/resources/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="/wsf-ops/resources/bootstrap/css/device.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <style>
        .error {
            color: #ee0d25;
        }
    </style>

</head>
    <body>

            <form class="form-device" method="POST" command="queryForm">
                <h2 class="form-device-heading">Please fill the form</h2>

                <label for="deviceId" class="sr-only">deviceId</label>
                <input type="text" name="deviceId" id="deviceId" class="form-control" placeholder="deviceId">
                <td></td>

                <label for="startTime" class="sr-only">startTime</label>
                <input type="text" name="startTime" id="startTime" class="form-control" placeholder="startTime">
                <td></td>


                <label for="endTime" class="sr-only">endTime</label>
                <input type="text" name="endTime" id="endTime" class="form-control" placeholder="endTime">
                <td></td>

                <label for="environment" class="sr-only">environment</label>
                <input type="text" name="environment" id="environment" class="form-control"
                       placeholder="daily or online">
                <td></td>

                <div class="checkbox">
                </div>
                <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

the `<form:error>`label can't be found in the page source code, so error information will not show up when input fails the validation. why is that?
the device.css is copied from bootstrap [sample](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/signin.css).

Answer (score 0):

The JSP form is processed on the server first, then the HTML is sent to the browser. That's why you don't see the `<form:errors/>` in your browser, as that's code for JSP, not HTML.

Do your validation errors show up in your browser window anyway?

If you're using Chrome browser you probably won't see the markup for validation errors in the HTML source as it does a fresh request when you open the source view window.

Comment: I can't see the validation errors, if I put sth wrong, it just returns a new page with all the input boxes blank.